# Is this React bug or an amazing React feature?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, react-state

I am trying to send an object with 10 array of rows to a component. 
The component needs to keep the old data and only concatinate the new array to the existing one.

While I was trying to check the array in componentDidUpdate and concat to my old state of data, I noticed I am getting twice data!

Then I removed the componentDidUpdate, without any extra setState, when new props is comming the state of array is concatinated!

This is strange, I do not know how it is happening. Is it a bug or a feature in React I am not aware of?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      allData: data
    });
  }
```

So that is all happening in terms of setState. When new props of data is coming, it is keep getting added to the allData !!!!

Comment: i think you should know about the react state and lifecycle. this [document](https://itnext.io/react-understanding-state-lifecycle-d45df5d2cf3f) is helpful to you.

Comment: It does not make any sense. I know the lifecycle, my point is I am not updating the allData and it automatically happening?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getDerivedStateFromProps which looks more appropriate for what you want to do